# How to center the content of a PDFormField?

Tags: java, pdfbox

Let's say I'm filling a PDF using AcroForms.

```java
File blankDocument = new File("blank-document.pdf");
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(blankDocument);
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = catalog.getAcroForm();

for (PDFormField formField : acroForm.getFields()) {
    if (formField.getPartialName().equals("name")) {
         formField.setValue("Allan");
    }
}

document.save("filled_document.pdf");
```

Is it possible to center the content of my `PDFormField`? The way it is now, it justs fills the field from left to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**before** calling setValue(), do this:

```
if (formField instanceof PDVariableText)
{
    PDVariableText txtFormField = (PDVariableText) formField;
    txtFormField.setQ(PDVariableText.QUADDING_CENTERED);
}
```